# Dagger2 singleton not actually a singleton issue

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have an object that I'm trying to inject into 3 fragments as a singleton, using `@Inject` annotations.

Component:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [(MyModule::class)])
interface MyComponent {

  fun inject(fragment: OneFragment)
  fun inject(fragment: TwoFragment)
  fun inject(fragment: ThreeFragment)

}
```

Module:

```
@Module
class MyModule(val view: MyView) {

  @Provides
  fun provideView(): MyView = view

  @Provides
  fun providePresenter(view: MyView,
                       myService: MyService): MyPresenter =
      MyPresenterImpl(view, myService)

}
```

MyPresenterImpl:

```
@Singleton
class MyPresenterImpl(override val view: MyView,
                      override val myService: MyService): MyPresenter {

  private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

  // other code (irrelevant)
}
```

Fragments:

```
class OneFragment : Fragment() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var myPresenter: MyPresenter

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, viewGroup: ViewGroup?,
                            bundle: Bundle?): View? {
    activity?.mainApplication?.appComponent?.plus(
        MyModule(activity as MyActivity))?.inject(this)

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, viewGroup, false)

    //other meaningless code

    return view
  }
}
```

However, the presenters that are injected into the fragments are not the same unique instance.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably aren't inheriting the presenter from the superscoped component, but creating a new one per each subcomponent.

Comment: That's not where you'd use @ Singleton.  @ Singleton should mark up the provider method, to tell Dagger that the returned value is a singleton.

Comment: It's okay to use `@Singleton` on the Presenter class. In fact, square recommends that the scope annotation belongs where you have it on the implementation as "an implementation detail". See the "Favor @Inject over @Provides" section of [this article](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/keeping-the-daggers-sharp-%EF%B8%8F-230b3191c3f). The problem is you should also annotate that constructor with `@Inject`. Put everything in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a `@Singleton` because you did not tell Dagger that it is. You put the scope on the presenter which would be fine if you were using constructor injection, but you aren't.

```
@Singleton // does nothing. you're not doing constructor injection.
class MyPresenterImpl(override val view: MyView,
                  override val myService: MyService): MyPresenter


// ...and in your module...


@Provides // where's the scope? it's unscoped.
fun providePresenter(view: MyView,
                  myService: MyService): MyPresenter =
    MyPresenterImpl(view, myService)
```

So you have two options. Either you use constructor injection, or you use a `@Provides`. You can't cherry pick and use a bit of each one.

### 1. Constructor injection

Just remove the `@Provides` annotated method in your module and slap an `@Inject` on your constructor.

```
@Singleton // NOW we're doing constructor injection -> singleton!
class MyPresenterImpl @Inject constructor(override val view: MyView,
                  override val myService: MyService): MyPresenter
```

There is no need for a module declaring it now. If you want to bind it to an interface you can use the `@Binds` annotation and continue using constructor injection...

```
@Binds // bind implementation to interface
abstract fun providePresenter(presenter : MyPresenterImpl) : MyPresenter
```

Since `MyPresenterImpl` is a `@Singleton` you don't have to declare `MyPresenter` as a singleton also. It will always use the singleton under the hood. (I believe it might even have a slight bigger performance penalty doing scopes on both.)

### 2. `@Provides method`

Remove the scope from your class (where it does nothing but confuse), and put it on the `@Provides` method instead. That's it.

```
@Singleton // singleton!
@Provides
fun providePresenter(view: MyView,
                  myService: MyService): MyPresenter =
    MyPresenterImpl(view, myService)
```

---

Scope on the class for constructor injection, or scope on the `@Provides` method if you're using that. Don't mix them up.

I'd personally recommend to go for constructor injetion whenever possible to do so as you don't have to manage/update the constructor calls yourself.

Comment: isn't singleton is just a scope annotation and only means that there will be a single object in component scope? And since each fragment is creating a new component a new presenter object will be created in case of `@Provides` ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal You're correct, but imho distinguishing between `@Singleton` and 'Singleton' in every other answer on stack overflow and pointing out the difference would lead to more confusion than it would prevent. `@Singleton` in the context of dagger always means a single instance *per `@Singleton` scoped component*, but there usually will only be one of those, which is why it most of the time will end up as an actual singleton.

Comment: This solution is wrong. Putting an Inject on a constructor does not mean that it will be automatically injected into classes where you use lateinit var myPresenter: MyPresenter - Using lateinit on a member variable absolutely requires that you use a component, which in turn requires a module. So contrary to your claim that no module is needed, it is required.

Comment: @AndroidDev having an `@Inject` annotated constructor enables Dagger to provide/inject the dependency the same way a `@Provides` annotated method, a `@Binds` method, or a `@BindsInstance` builder method does. I didn't claim that Dagger did anything automatically, `lateinit` is a Kotlin construct and has nothing to do with Dagger by itself, I'm assuming you mean field injection? Of course you need a component, but components don't require modules. This isn't really the place for discussion, so if you have a specific issue then please ask a new question and provide more details.